# Converting a csv to an xts using QuantQuote Data

Tags: r, csv, time-series, xts, zoo

I know that there are other similar posts, but I still couldn't figure out how to coerce the data I had to an XTS object.

https://quantquote.com/sample/SPY_MINUTE_TRADE.csv
contains a csv file of minute bar data of the SPY.

Column 1 is Data in YYYYMMDD format.
Column 2 is Time in HHMM format.

I want to create an XTS object indexed in a very standard YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM format.

I have been told that using read.zoo to import the csv is a good way to do it but can't seem to make it work.

Any advice on how to about it?

EDIT: Almost there but I'm still missing something

```
datzoo <- read.zoo(file="SPY_MINUTE_TRADE.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE, index.column=1:2,
                   format="%Y%m%d %H%M", tz="", colClasses = rep(c("character", "numeric"), c(2, 8)))
```

RETURNS

```
Error in read.zoo(file = "SPY_MINUTE_TRADE.csv", sep = ",", header = TRUE, : index has 210 bad entries at data rows: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11....
```

Comment: This is basically the same question as [How to read date time from 2 columns with zoo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680940/how-to-read-date-time-from-2-columns-with-zoo)

Comment: Thanks Josh I will give a look and see if I can get it working

Comment: Almost there but I'm still missing something
'

datzoo <- read.zoo(file="SPY_MINUTE_TRADE.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE, 
                 index.column=1:2, format="%Y%m%d %H%M", tz="", 
                 colClasses = rep(c("character", "numeric"), c(2, 8)))
'
RETURNS
Error in read.zoo(file = "SPY_MINUTE_TRADE.csv", sep = ",", header = TRUE,  : 
  index has 210 bad entries at data rows: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11....

Comment: sorry that looks like crap... im a newb and couldnt figure out how to post it as a pretty block :(

Comment: Edit it into your question...

Comment: The times in your file don't have leading zeros, so you'll have to prepend them yourself using something like `sprintf('%04d', 210)` or some such.

Comment: will give it a go, thanks as always!!
I'll let u know how it went. Appreciate it

Comment: success!
You are a saint!